# SAVING FILE to excel using vb.net from vb6 code

Tags: vb.net, vb6

i have a vb6 code tha needs to work on vb.net

```
 Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim FileHandle%

    strFilter = "Comma Seperated File (*.csv)|*.csv"
    CDMAIN.Filter = strFilter
    CDMAIN.ShowSave
    If CDMAIN.FileName <> "" Then
        strFileName = CDMAIN.FileName
        strText = Text1.Text
        FileHandle% = FreeFile
```

'''''''''''''''''''Im having difficulty converting the following line of codes

```
        Open strFileName For Output As #FileHandle%
        MousePointer = vbHourglass
        Print #FileHandle%, strText
        MousePointer = vbDefault
        Close #FileHandle%
    End If
```

the function saves data to excel file

Comment: there is not a great deal involved in converting that.  how far have you gotten?

Comment: i edited my post. im on the last few lines

Comment: You'll want to use something like the System.IO.StreamWriter.  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) shows you how it works and gives a great example.

Comment: As for the `MousePointer`, use `Cursors.Current = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Open strFileName For Output As #FileHandle%
    MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Print #FileHandle%, strText
    MousePointer = vbDefault
    Close #FileHandle%
```

translates to a VB.NET code:

```
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Using fs As New StreamWriter(strFileName, False)
        fs.WriteLine(strText)
    End Using
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```